# Writing to a text file at a specific position Java

Tags: java, file, io

Suppose I have a file called "Bill.txt".

The format:

ItemType ItemName Price

Now I want to add a new Description field. This description must be written next to the price.

The problem is, how to determine the position where to write it.

Comment: I must use FileWriter for this

Comment: I am not replacing.. i need to add

Comment: I would suggest reading in the entire file while knowing the descriptions for each line, then writing the file from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I agree with user2085282. You could read in the file using:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Bill.txt"));
```

For each line, the Reader reads, add like a semicolon or some character that should not be in the original file. Then in array split the string based on that character.

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
          //string = line + semicolon
          // then set an array to split(;)


    }
```

Then in another loop have like result += array[i] + description;

Then write the string in a new file